# How to select a value in a range with QuickCheck?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck, hspec

I have the following code I am using for creating a challenge on the following site : [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/)

```
describe "Random cases" $ do
    it "It should handle random test cases" $ 
        property $ prop_check where 
            prop_check  (Positive x) = solution x == ref_sol x
            --- ref_sol function
```

I would like to set the value of `x` in prop_check to be a positive int greater than 4 and at max a five-digit number (no more than five digits, i.e : max value = 99999).

How would I go about approaching it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use QuickCheck's `choose` function to select a value in an inclusive range. The easiest approach is probably to write `prop_check` with `do` notation:

```
prop_check :: Gen Bool
prop_check = do
  x <- choose (5, 99999) :: Gen Integer
  return $ solution x == ref_sol x
```

Here, `x` is an `Integer` value between `5` and `99999`.

Depending on the types of `solution` and `ref_sol`, you may not need the `Gen Integer` type annotation on the first line. Since I didn't know the types of those functions, though, I had to add the annotation.